# How to Generate QR Code for Microsoft Authenticator Work or School Recovery

Tags: office365, azure, azure-activedirectory, microsoft

I've created a Microsoft Authenticator backup for several Microsoft 365/Azure Work or School accounts, but when recovering to a new device these need additional verification in the form of a QR code. I can't find how to make this QR code as an administrator, and have found no links on Microsoft pages ([e.g. Recovery Process](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/back-up-and-recover-account-credentials-in-the-authenticator-app-bb939936-7a8d-4e88-bc43-49bc1a700a40)) to direct on how to do this.

The closest I got was this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/48719) on GitHub, but it likewise does not show how an admin can in Azure AD or Microsoft 365 Admin Center create a new QR code.

Thanks.

EDIT: For example please see the below screenshot from Microsoft's recovery process. It mentions that the admin will generate a QR code (Step 2) but does not link to any instructions for admins to do this.
[image]

Comment: You don't need the QR code you only need the Secret Code, do you have access to that, what exactly was generated when you created the authenticator?  You should edit your question instead of replying with a comment.

Comment: Added screenshot from Microsoft's doc to clarify. It doesn't mention using a secret code. I would like to know Microsoft's way of generating the QR code in case this is faster than adding each account back manually.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unintuitive.
I was about to go through the process to delete the Mirosoft Authenticator from mysignins.microsoft.com/security-info and I was going to set it up again as a new method, but instead of deleting it, I just clicked Add sign-in method, selected Authenticator app, and it gave me a QR code to set up the app, scan this one and it will active the existing method instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Did this happen when the actioned required warning (pic above) was displayed? To get to mysignins.microsoft.com I had to use another authentication method before I could reactivate the account.

In short, I wanted to know Microsoft's way of generating the QR code as an admin in case this was faster than adding each account back manually.

Answer (score -2):

If the user is able to access https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/proofup.aspx?proofup=1 this lets them generate a QR code for the new device

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this will still require the user to authenticate via MFA in most orgs (e.g. Conditional Access policies), so they'd be unable to sign in to address the Action Required screen (pic above) without having a second MFA method separate to the attempted recovery from back up.